# Excel VBA code for data validation with multiple selections in one cell - for multiple colums

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I need to create an excel sheet for a survey. Some of the questions should have the option to select multiple answers out of a drop down menu.

I have already the data validation for those questions and it's all working. However, I can't make it so I'm able to select multiple options from the drop down menu. I've used a few sample codes, making the necessary changes and still can't make it work. Anyone can help with the VBA code?
Here are all the columns in which this should apply to:
I, N, Q, W, AB, AD and AF (I'm assuming they should be input as number, so here you go: 9, 14, 17, 23, 28, 30 and 32).

The selections should all be input in the same cell, separated by commas.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't write a specific example without seeing the code you tried, but in general you can concatenate the old cell value and the new selected value from the drop-down with the `&` symbol.

```
cell.value = cell.value & ", " & dropDownResult.value
```

Where `cell` is a range object you specify to hold the result, and `dropDownResult` is a range object with your dropdown cell.

You can check this more detailed general solution which you could alter to fit your specific approach.
https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html

Comment: Thank you! I'm actually not very good with coding, so I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I used the code from this site as example: https://www.contextures.com/excel-data-validation-multiple.html